# Highest weight of the fundamental representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I'm studying the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ and I have a problem involving its highest weight. I have used a basis of ones off the diagonal and Cartan subalgebra $\mathrm{span}(h_1,h_2)\vert h_1 = \mathrm{diag}(1,-1,0), h_2 = \mathrm{diag}(0,1,-1)$. I can see that in the **3** representation, there is a vector with weight (1,0): $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ as well as a vector with weight (-1,1): $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_(representation_theory)#Theorem_of_the_highest_weight) there should be a unique highest weight, which I understand to mean that the difference between it and all other weights is a positive linear combination of the fundamental weights (in this case (1,0) and (0,1)), but the weight (-1,1) seems to violate this in the fundamental representation **3** with highest weight (1,0). Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

After looking around this site, I found a post saying that a highest weight is either higher than or does not compare to every other weight. This does seem to resolve my problem; however, it still contrasts with the Wikipedia article I linked before as well as [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_highest_weight). Where has this disparity come from, and why in my $\mathfrak{sl}_3$ case can you not just as well consider (-1,1) as a highest weight of the **3** representation?

Comment: I assume your fundamental weights, spelled out as linear maps, are $diag(a,b,c) \mapsto a$ (called $(1,0)$) and $diag(a,b,c) \mapsto c$ (called $(0,1)$). But then, it seems to me that the weight to the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ is not $(-1,1)$ but rather $(-1,-1)$?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking that they would be $diag(a,b,c) \mapsto a - b$ and $diag(a,b,c) \mapsto b - c$ since as per my calculations the simple coroots were the elements I listed of the Cartan subalgebra, and so the fundamental weights would be exactly dual to these, but if I have made an oversight here I would appreciate any corrections.

Comment: The two elements you have there, call them $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, are (a choice of) *simple roots*. The fundamental weights are somehow "shorter" than those (the weight lattice is "finer" than the root lattice: It is very worthwhile to draw them both here). Quite obviously $diag(a,b,c)$ acts on $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ via multiplication with $a$, not with $a-b$. This fundamental weight, expressed in terms of the simple roots, is $\frac23 \alpha_1 + \frac13 \alpha_2$.

Comment: Once you've sorted that out, read closely and see that actually the highest weight is characterized by the difference between it and all other weights being a positive linear combination of **positive/simple roots** (NOT: fundamental weights). In this case, it makes a difference. With our above choices, it should be easy to see that this fundamental weight, $diag(a,b,c) \mapsto a$, is the highest weight of the standard three-dimensional representation.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I think that should clear things up.